# Azue Web Role web application restarts [w3wp]

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

I have an application running on Azure Cloud Service, that consists of Web Role and Worker Role. I will focus on Web Role here.

Lately I've discovered many entries in our Event Log, saying that application has restarted. This happens randomly, several times a day.

We are logging this message in Global.asax.cs `Application_Start()`

I've investigated machine's Event Viewer, and found that these logs correspond to entries in Windows Azure log like this:

```
Role initialized. Process ID: 568, Process Name: w3wp Role environment . INITIALIZED
```

I couldn't see any pattern in restart times, either. Sometimes it is 3 times in a 2 hour period, and the other time it's working 12hrs perfectly.

Also there are no Application errors in event viewer, that would have similar timestamp to these logs.

I know that IIS recycles application every 29 hours, but we have altered this behaviour, modifying `appPool.Recycling.PeriodicRestart.Schedule` in overriden `RoleEntryPoint.OnStart()`.

What can cause `w3wp` process to restart?
This also happens for by Worker Role, but I haven't investigated it yet, and I assume that where would be no `w3wp` process involved.

Comment: If you have not tried it already write a custom log in the OnStop() method of the role and see if you can find anything. Also enable trace and see the onstop event trace. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/the-right-way-to-handle-azure-onstop-events/

Comment: When a role recycles, that generally means that the WAIISHOST.exe process will be restarted as well (for webroles). Worker roles use another process but the idea is simillar.

What has helped me numerous times, is to debug Waiishost with the WinDBG tool provided in the AzureTools package. Information on how to use it and where to obtain it can be found at:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kwill/2013/10/03/troubleshooting-scenario-7-role-recycling/ 

As you say that the recycling happens intermittently in your case, it might be best to just leave the tool running until the role recycle occurs.